# ImportError no module named 'playsound'

Tags: python, import, pip, python-playsound

I did

```
pip install playsound
Downloading/unpacking playsound
  Downloading playsound-1.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: playsound
Successfully installed playsound
Cleaning up...
```

and it installed playsound (at least is said so), but when i type

```
python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Sep 16 2019, 19:58:00) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import playsound
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'playsound'
```

there is no module?
Why does this happen? 
Oh, I just found out there is no problem when i try to import this when i use python2. There must be a problem with python3 and playsound? How do i import it with python3?

Comment: Do you have python2 on your system? If so then it's lilkely `pip` will install into your system python2 env and you'll need to use `pip3` to install to your system python3 env.

Comment: is it possible you installed it for the wrong version of python? try `pip3 install playsound`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most probably you have both python2 and python3 installed with their package managers, so pip refers to the package manager for python2
instead use

```
pip3 install playsound
```

and it should work fine.